# javascript doesn't rendered arrow buttons in slick.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, carousel, slick.js

Hi i have problem while working with slick.js in fact javascript doesn't have rendered arrow buttons, even though value of arrows is true by default i set it on true value again, but it doesn't become  enabled.

```
$j(document).on('ready', function() {
$j(".regular").slick({
  dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    rtl: true,
    arrows:true,
    prevArrow: '<button><img src="/skin/frontend/sbase/abzarmart/images/prvarw.svg"/></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button><img src="/skin/frontend/sbase/abzarmart/images/nxtarw.svg"/></button>',
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 5,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 4,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                infinite: false,
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 2
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

});

notice: i should be used $j for jquery because in my web site prototype.js was using!

Comment: `arrows` is true by default. There may be something wrong with your `prevArrow` and `nextArrow` markup. Maybe take those out and see if the default arrows appear

Comment: at the first time i didn't set default value to arrows , prevArrow or nextArrow but when i saw it didn't work i set default again